# Is there a way to have CSS borders outside the box(div)? Or alternative solution 

Tags: css, border

I have this menu here[image]

I want the highlighting(hover) to extend to the edge of the outside box(service menu). Just like how the popout menu is. The menu itself is contained in another div - [image]

I don't think it is possible to have negative borders the same way you can have negative padding.

Anyone have a good idea on how to get the highlight of the menu to extend to the edge of the outside box on hover?

This is Drupal w/ Nice Menu by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a margin issue, trying changing the margin to padding, should work almost exactly the same and go to the edge.

EDIT Or set the width of the out div to be the same as the inner div.

Comment: I can't really change the margin or padding because that box must conform to the same styles as everything else in the sidebar. Like the text must be 15px from the left, and so on. I was hoping for a way, hacky or not, to overflow the border, or outline, or something I haven't thought of.

Comment: What if you try changing it from margin to padding, with the same values, though? That should have the same spacing, with the background and borders being on the outside of the padding instead of the inside. Also, I'm pretty sure that borders are outside the div. You could try giving it a border of like, 20px on the left and right, and see if that works.

Comment: Also, you could try absolute positioning, but that's a pain.

Answer (score 4):

You should use box-sizing property:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

This will make the border and padding fit inside the elements dimensions as opposed to outside.

Answer (score 0):

use Combination of CSS BOX model with outline.

margin:

```
padding:
border: line-size style color;
outline:line-size style color;
box-sizing:border-box (webkit);
```

example:

```
padding:2px;
margin:0;
border: 1px solid grey;
outline: 1px solid grey;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```